# Im noob at Vuforia, so Vuforia can't recognize my image?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

First of all I'm noon at Vuforia and Unity. I want to make memorybook to my girlfriend. We have photograph album and I want to use them as target images and want to show videos in program. I have downloaded core package, and tried imagetarget works like charm. But when I change target image to my database pictures it cannot recognize. Also Vuforia give 5 stars to my images. I don't know what am I missing? Can you help me?

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose. There's several settings that need to be changed in order to use your own image databases, have you done *both* the image target *and* the AR camera?

Comment: I only changed targetimage from core sample. What should I do in ARCamera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the AR Camera's settings. One of them deals with what databases the camera has loaded.

I believe it's called "Active databases" or "Loaded databases," its been a while since I've messed around with Vuforia, so I can't remember the exact name.

You need to make sure to include your database in the list of active/loaded ones.